# Adding Proximity target in AdWords API gives CampaignCriterionError.CONCRETE_TYPE_REQUIRED

Tags: google-ads-api

*Edit: Google has confirmed this is a bug in the client libraries: [https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/issues/20](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/issues/20_)*

I am trying to add a Proximity targeting criterion to a campaign using the AdWords API. I am using the JAX-WS version of the API (because I need it to run on App Engine). I am able to add Proximity criteria with the AXIS version of the API, so I'm wondering if there is a bug in the API.

This is the code I'm using to add the Proximity criterion:

```
    // Get the CampaignService.
CampaignCriterionServiceInterface campaignCriterionService =
    adWordsServices.get(session, CampaignCriterionServiceInterface.class);

Proximity proximity = new Proximity();
GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint();
geoPoint.setLatitudeInMicroDegrees(43633941);
geoPoint.setLongitudeInMicroDegrees(-79398718);
proximity.setGeoPoint(geoPoint);
proximity.setRadiusDistanceUnits(ProximityDistanceUnits.KILOMETERS);
proximity.setRadiusInUnits(10.0);

List<CampaignCriterionOperation> operations = new ArrayList<CampaignCriterionOperation>();
for (Criterion criterion : new Criterion[] { proximity }) {
  CampaignCriterionOperation operation = new CampaignCriterionOperation();
  CampaignCriterion campaignCriterion = new CampaignCriterion();
  campaignCriterion.setCampaignId(campaignId);
  campaignCriterion.setCriterion(criterion);
  operation.setOperand(campaignCriterion);
  operation.setOperator(Operator.ADD);
  operations.add(operation);
}

CampaignCriterionReturnValue result =
    campaignCriterionService.mutate(operations);

// Display campaigns.
for (CampaignCriterion campaignCriterion : result.getValue()) {
  System.out.printf("Campaign criterion with campaign id '%s', criterion id '%s', "
      + "and type '%s' was added.\n", campaignCriterion.getCampaignId(), campaignCriterion
      .getCriterion().getId(), campaignCriterion.getCriterion().getCriterionType());
}
```

This is basically the code from https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords_axis/src/main/java/adwords/axis/v201402/targeting/AddCampaignTargetingCriteria.java where criteria have been replaced by a Proximity criterion and with classes from com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.* replaced by their com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.* equivalents.

When run (with the appropriate information ads.properties), I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <ResponseHeader xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201402">
            <requestId>0004fd8ef85c5a600aec338ad0007a98</requestId>
            <serviceName>CampaignCriterionService</serviceName>
            <methodName>mutate</methodName>
            <operations>1</operations>
            <responseTime>363</responseTime>
        </ResponseHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>[CampaignCriterionError.CONCRETE_TYPE_REQUIRED @ operations[0].operand.criterion]</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ApiExceptionFault xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201402">
                    <message>[CampaignCriterionError.CONCRETE_TYPE_REQUIRED @ operations[0].operand.criterion]</message>
                    <ApplicationException.Type>ApiException</ApplicationException.Type>
                    <errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CampaignCriterionError">
                        <fieldPath>operations[0].operand.criterion</fieldPath>
                        <trigger/>
                        <errorString>CampaignCriterionError.CONCRETE_TYPE_REQUIRED</errorString>
                        <ApiError.Type>CampaignCriterionError</ApiError.Type>
                        <reason>CONCRETE_TYPE_REQUIRED</reason>
                    </errors>
                </ApiExceptionFault>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>
```

I suspect that something is going wrong when composing the xml that is sent to AdWords, because the outgoing request looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header>
        <RequestHeader xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201402">
            <userAgent>Test (AwApi-Java, AdWords-AppEngine/1.28.0, Common-Java/1.28.0, JAX-WS/Unknown, Java/1.7.0_45, maven)</userAgent>
            <developerToken>REMOVEDFORSAFETYREASONS</developerToken>
            <clientCustomerId>XYZ-XYZ-XYYZ</clientCustomerId>
        </RequestHeader>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <mutate xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201402" xmlns:ns2="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/video/v201402">
            <operations>
                <operator>ADD</operator>
                <operand>
                    <campaignId>185385127</campaignId>
                    <criterion/>
                </operand>
            </operations>
        </mutate>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Notice that the criterion tag is completely empty.

Running the same code, but with the AXIS version of the API works and produces the following  outgoing xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns1:RequestHeader xmlns:ns1="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201402" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
            <ns1:clientCustomerId>XYZ-XYZ-XYYZ</ns1:clientCustomerId>
            <ns1:developerToken>REMOVEDFORSAFETY</ns1:developerToken>
            <ns1:userAgent>Test (AwApi-Java, AdWords-Axis/1.28.0, Common-Java/1.28.0, Axis/1.4, Java/1.7.0_45, jars)</ns1:userAgent>
            <ns1:validateOnly>false</ns1:validateOnly>
            <ns1:partialFailure>false</ns1:partialFailure>
        </ns1:RequestHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <mutate xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201402">
            <operations>
                <operator>ADD</operator>
                <operand>
                    <campaignId>185385127</campaignId>
                    <criterion xmlns:ns2="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201402" xsi:type="ns2:Proximity">
                        <ns2:geoPoint>
                            <ns2:latitudeInMicroDegrees>43633941</ns2:latitudeInMicroDegrees>
                            <ns2:longitudeInMicroDegrees>-79398718</ns2:longitudeInMicroDegrees>
                        </ns2:geoPoint>
                        <ns2:radiusDistanceUnits>KILOMETERS</ns2:radiusDistanceUnits>
                        <ns2:radiusInUnits>10.0</ns2:radiusInUnits>
                    </criterion>
                </operand>
            </operations>
        </mutate>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Notice that in the latter case, the criterion includes the geolocation and radius as one would expect.

Other types of criteria, like Location and Language work fine both in the AXIS and JAX-WS versions.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in the v201409 version (release 1.34.0) of the AdWords API. Upgrading to that version fixed the issue for me.